# Arduino Bluno <-> Mac/Linux

Tags: linux, macos, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluno

I'm trying to find a way (if it's even possible) to connect a Bluno (Arduino UNO + BLE) directly to a pc/mac.
All information I find about it is to connect Bluno to the apps dfrobot provides for Android and IOS.

http://www.dfrobot.com/wiki/index.php/Bluno_SKU:DFR0267

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Do you want to connect over BLE or some other way? There is a lot of material in the documents section on the page you linked in.

Comment: On OSX use LightBlue as a BLE explorer, discover devices, examine profiles etc. Its a free download from the OSX AppStore

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm trying to do the same.